# Responsive Design Issue At the 320px and 480px Viewport Sizes

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I am having a difficult time figuring out why a div is being pushed down and out of another div.

If you go to the following link

http://www.chrismazzochi.com/index.php?subject=6

This page contains a contact form, and if you scale down to the 480px landscape or 320px portrait size viewport dimension, or view this site on an iPhone, you will see that there is a bit of a gap between the label and the input.  If you use Firebug you will be able to see that the label and input in question is .styled_label and .styled_input respectively.

First I have used negative top margins to align the inputs because they were being pushed down and out of the .form_fields container.  I don't want to do this.  And I also can't get these input fields to budge over to the left.

Can anyone help?
I'd appreciate it. 
Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you. change the mazzo_style.css in line number 1005.

Change `margin-right:1%;` to `margin-right:21.9592%`

Comment: I appreciate that Faisal.  Thanks for taking the time to figure that out.  That did help me out.  I'm grateful.

Comment: My pleasure Chris but you still didn't accept my answer & if is it really help you then you didn't vote it up? :-)